# iOS: Release after autorelease

Tags: ios

This can't be right... or maybe it is. I was looking at the source code for something called ShareKit, written by some guy named Nathan, and I noticed that he autoreleases a view that later, in dealloc, he releases.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the allocation code for that object.  But I suspect that his logic is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly why you think it's wrong. For example this is entirely valid code which exhibits the same sort of thing as you are seeing:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *someNumber;

@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize someNumber;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]])) {
        self.someNumber = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5] autorelease]; // retain count = 1 (alloc) - 1 (on next drain) + 1 (retaining property) = 1
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [someNumber release]; // retain count = 0
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

There's nothing wrong with a `release` happening after an `autorelease`.

Another bit of code that would be valid (although completely pointless!):

```
NSNumber *someNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:5]; // retain count = 1
[someNumber retain]; // retain count = 2
[someNumber autorelease]; // retain count = 2 (-1 on next drain) = 1
[someNumber release]; // retain count = 1 (-1 on next drain) = 0
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is completely valid? I cannot think of any reason to blend autorelease pools with manual releases.

Comment: My first example shows why it's useful. Assigning to a property is often done like that so that it's all on one line. Then you `release` `someNumber` in `dealloc` because you're being destroyed so you're `release`-ing everything you own.

Comment: By the way, this is what Nathan is doing: id foo = [[[Class alloc] init] autorelease]; [foo release];

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. That's what I'm doing in my first example as well.

Comment: Note that you are *always* using both autorelease pools and manual releases, even in an ARC world this is happening - just the compiler adds the `release`s for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no;
Autorelease pool will just call a release for each instance it has in list on it's drain.